# How draw images with hardware acceleration on all platforms?

Tags: java, image, awt, hardware-acceleration

I've created 256x256 image with red=x and alpha=y:

```
    int[] pix = new int[256*256];
    for (int i = 0; i < pix.length; ++i)
        pix[i] = i << 16;
    BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    img1.setRGB(0, 0, 256, 256, pix, 0, 256);
```

and have copied to volatile image:

```
    VolatileImage img2 = canvas.createVolatileImage(256, 256);
    img2.createGraphics().drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
```

When i draw BufferedImage to canvas, it incorrectly process alpha and not accelerated (0.9msec for drawImage):

[image: invalid alpha]

When i draw VolatileImage, it process alpha and accelerated (0.03ms):

[image: valid aplpha]

But it under Windows. Under MacOS i see different result. For BufferedImage it do not process alpha, but accelerated, for VolatileImage it process alpha correctly, but NOT accelerated. (Or maybe both not accelerated, just software processing of BufferedImage much faster).

Question - how correctly draw image with correct alpha processing and with acceleration on all platforms.

ps. img2.setAccelerationPriority(1) has no any effect.

pps. i was wrong, it not correct alpha processing in second case, it just precalculated image with alpha applied to default background color of cavas.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

This setting resolved problem with acceleration, now there 0.004msec for drawImage

And there was no problem with alpha processing at all, i just draw same image with alpha 1000 times at same place for time testing and it caused such ugly picture